# Can not connect to gnome-look.org

Tags: internet, connection, webserver

For a long time I can not connect to gnome-look.org. All the rest of Internet works fine. It's just that one site. I checked on sites like **downforeveryoneorjustme.com**. It says it's just me. I use usb modem, and was always able to connect to gnome-look.org. But now I can not. And it's been for several weeks. Neither under windows, nor under any linux from vm. What could be the cause?

Comment: Probably your ISP. What does `tracert` tell you?

Comment: `stas@stas-vm:~$ traceroute gnome-look.org
traceroute to gnome-look.org (46.101.238.240), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.133.2)  1.568 ms  1.482 ms  1.423 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *`
and continues like that

Comment: `stas@stas-vm:~$ tracert6 gnome-look.org
gnome-look.org port 33434: Name or service not known`

Comment: cant find `tracert` command

Comment: That looks like an issue with your ISP.